# How to import a TypeScript class in visual studio "TypeScript HTML App" template?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm just create an empty project of visual studio's "HTML Application with TypeScript" template. So, VS automatically build *.js files from *.ts files.

I want to import one class to other in TypeScript way like

```
import {Person} from './person';
```

and don't want to client(browser) gets *.ts scripts from server.

It's there any way to do that? Because browser throws an exception when I try to import class

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Problem caused from `tsconfig` file

you can change `module` property to `system` or`es2015` instead of `commonjs`
because CommonJS modules are NodeJS like modules that uses `require` method for importing external modules.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true
    },
}
```

In case of Visual Studio project you can do so

1. right click on project in `Solution Explorer`, then click on `Properties`

[image: TypeScript project properties]

2. Open `TypeScript Build` tab

[image: open TypeScript build tab]

3. Change `CommonJS` to `System` or `ES 2015`, depended on type of project you want to create

[image: Module system]

Comment: thanks. I try, but it doesn't work. system requires SystemJS in client and SystemJS send get requests to server to get *.ts files.

Comment: or you can change to `ES2015`

Comment: "system" compiler generate a JavaScript code, where call unknown "require" function, and throw an exception about that.

Comment: do you try and it's works? maybe i use an old version of typescript

Comment: @GrigorAleksanyan with typescript you need to use bundling systems like `RequireJS`,`SystemJS` or `Browserify`